# Xcode c bad_acces code 2 error

Tags: c, string, xcode, reverse, string-literals

Hi, I'm kinda new to programming and i'm trying to code a function in c that reverse a string.

```
char *ft_strrev(char *str)
{
char x;
int i = 0,j = 0,k;

while(str[i] != '\0')
{
    i++;
}
k = i;
while(j < k/2)
{
    x = str[j];
    str[j] = str[i]; //here is the error
    str[i] = x;
    j++;
    i--;
}

return str;
}
```

I want to get cba when I put abc in function.

Comment: The statement  is logically wrong however are you trying to reverse a string literal? You may not modify string literals.

Comment: I don't know what do you want to say with literal reverse.Can you explain more for a beginner like me?

Comment: I think you are calling the function like ft_strrev( "abc" ); or like char *s = "abc"; ft_strrev( s ); You should call it like char s[] = "abc"; ft_strrev( s );

Comment: Yes, if that isn't correct, how should I call the function?

Comment: You should declare a character array as I showed in the updated previous comment.

Comment: I got it, I did it and the error is gone but now it doesn't show anything when I print the string.

Comment: Read at last my answer.:)

Answer (score 1):

For starters this code snippet contains a logical error.

```
x = str[j];
str[j] = str[i]; //here is the error
str[i] = x;
```

For the initial value of the index `i` `str[i]` is equal to `'\0'`. So as result an empty string will be obtained.

The code snippet should look like

```
x = str[j];
str[j] = str[i-1]; //here is the error
str[i-1] = x;
```

As for the error then it seems you are trying to reverse a string literal. You may not change string literals. Any attempt to modify a string literal result in in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals):

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

You could call the function the following way declaring a character array and initializing it with a string literal.

```
char s[] = "abc";

ft_strrev( s );
```